# Часть кода Qt/C++ вынести в DLL

Tags: c++, qt

Проект Qt/С++ для Windows/Linux. Почти всё, реализовано на классах. Несколько модулей необходимо вынести в dll/so. Как это сделать с минимальными затратами?

edit 1.

Собрал библиотеку с TEMPLATE = lib в файле проекта, получил MyLib.dll и MyLib.a файлы.

Не понятно, как теперь сконфигурировать основной проект, чтобы использовать классы и всё остальное из этой dll без их исходников (без *.cpp файлов)

Comment: абсолютно непонятный вопрос. В чем проблема то? TEMPLATE = lib - не знакомо, в файле проекта?

Comment: Сказывается привычка работать в большом проекте не разбитом на библиотеки. Собрал  библиотеку отдельно с TEMPLATE = lib. Но как её теперь подключить к основному проекту?

Comment: -lбиблиотека без первогого lib. Например libalfa библиотека, в проекте LIBS += -lalfa. Если не в стандартном месте находится, то указать что то вроде LIBS += -L"d:/library" -lalfa,  для Windows, ну и аналогично для Linux

Comment: Или в `Creator` есть `Add Library to project`

Comment: да, еще иногда полезно бывает написать в коде типа     app.addLibraryPath(app.applicationFilePath()); В частности, для Windows так делаю всегда, а в Linux все же предпочитаю размещать библиотеку в стандартном месте /usr/local/lib[64]

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно ещё пишется MyLib.pri файл, в котором описывается подключение, например:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
HEADERS += $$PWD/MyLib.h
LIBS+=$$PWD/MyLib.lib
```

Затем в основном проекте делается примерно так:

```
include(../MyLib/MyLib.pri)
```

Ну и желательно описать общую сборку, как TEMPLATE = subdirs